# How to Copy a table row details to visual studio form

Tags: sql, vb.net

> I have a table try - "uid,pwd,mob and name."

```
CL001 abc 9876589 admin
CL002 def 8909898 admin2
```

I want to call the values in a visual basic form from the table and **display the values in corresponding textbox** .I know the SQL Query for this --> `select * from try where uid="CL001"`

Comment: Don't suppose you've read the chapter in the book called databases?

Comment: It is in Visual studio!
i Know SQL Language but how to use in visual studio vb form application?
i dont know!

Comment: i could do the insert comment successfully!  "Insert into tablename(column1,column2)values('" & textbox1.text& "','" & textbox2.text& "')"

Comment: Dear Friends pls do not give me negative points because i have lots of doubts!! and my last account i couldn't ask any more questions that's why i created this also i won't be able 2 reply or comment for 5 days as i will be on my umra (pilgrimage) so please be patient and help me please....

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will allow you to execute a SELECT statement on your database. Before you call it you must declare a new datatable like:

```
Dim dt as New DataTable
dt = doSQL("select * from try where uid='CL001'")

    Public Function DoSQL(ByVal sqlCmd As String) As DataTable
    Dim cmd As New SQL.SqlCommand()
    Dim cnn As New SQL.SqlConnection(My.Settings.cnnString) ' your connection string here
    Dim sqlDT As New DataTable
    With cmd
        .Connection = cnn
        .CommandText = sqlCmd
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    End With
    Dim da As New SQL.SqlDataAdapter()
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da.Fill(sqlDT)

    Return sqlDT

End Function
```

The datatable will have the records that match. So if you know there is going to be only 1 record you could do something like:

```
textbox.text = dt.Rows(0).Item("uid").ToString
```

Or you could bind it to a textbox and use the bindingmanagerbase to keep track of the position for you like:

```
Private WithEvents bm As BindingManagerBase ' Class scope

Private Sub partBind(ByVal dt As DataTable)
txtBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "uid")
End Sub
```

You can then control flipping through record with bm.position like so:

```
Private Sub btnNavClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click, btnPrevious.Click, btnLast.Click, btnFirst.Click
    Dim btnClicked As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

    Select Case btnClicked.Name
        Case "btnNext"
            If bm.Position < bm.Count - 1 Then
                bm.Position += 1
            Else
                bm.Position = 0
            End If

        Case "btnPrevious"
            If bm.Position > 0 Then
                bm.Position -= 1
            Else
                bm.Position = bm.Count
            End If
            bm.Position -= 0
        Case "btnLast"
            bm.Position = bm.Count
        Case "btnFirst"
            bm.Position = 0
    End Select

End Sub
```